# Poor performance with python running on t2.micro, taking longer and longer to do I/O operation I believe

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I have this python script running on an Amazon EC2 (t2.micro) instance and I am noticing very bad performance, I figure it is probably because of the I/O that I am doing within it but its' incredibly poor. as time passes it takes longer and longer to complete the pollingPriceForTickerSymbol FUNCTION ; readData  FUNCTION ; averagesDoIt  FUNCTION  ; letsSeeHowWeDid  FUNCTION.

I've played around with inserting print statements to see what's going on and when I check the %CPU usage it is at 99%. I there a better way of doing this code?  And/or point to me what I am doing wrong here.

```
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email
import time
import robin_stocks as r
import shutil
from datetime import timedelta

# -------------------------------------------------
#
#
# ------------------------------------------------
running = False

counter = 0
currOpen = 0.00
currHigh = 0.00
currLow = 0.00
currClose = 0.00

#shorterVal = 5               # for daily data seems to work fine
#longerVal = 10               # for daily data seems to work fine
shorterVal = 10
longerVal = 20


shorterAvg = []
longerAvg = []

dohlcACv = []

cursor = -1
inPosition = False
boughtPrice = 0.00
soldPrice = 0.00
profit = 0.00

alreadyExperiencedDeathCross = False

numOfLosses = 0
numOfWins = 0

tickerSymb = "aapl"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def getLoggedIntoRH():

    try:
        #
        #
        login = r.login("jimom","2") ###############
        #

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def pollingPriceForTickerSymbol(i):

    try:
        #
        global tickerSymb
        #
        resp2 = r.stocks.get_stock_historicals(tickerSymb,"5minute", "week")
        #
        f = open("4reel.txt", "w")
        for x in range(len(resp2)):
            tempString = ""
            for key in resp2[x]:
                if "begins" in key:
                    tempString2 = str(resp2[x][key]) + ","
                if "open" in key:
                    tempString3 = str(resp2[x][key]) + ","
                if "high" in key:
                    tempString4 = str(resp2[x][key]) + ","
                if "low" in key:
                    tempString5 = str(resp2[x][key]) + ","
                if "close" in key:
                    tempString6 = str(resp2[x][key]) + "," + str(resp2[x][key]) + ","
                if "volume" in key:
                    tempString7 = str(resp2[x][key]) + "\n"
            tempString = tempString2 + tempString3 + tempString4 + tempString5 + tempString6 + tempString7
            f.write(tempString)
            #print(key, '->', resp2[x][key])
        f.close()
        #

        return resp2
        #

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))



# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1



# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def readData():
    #
    try:
        file1 = open('4reel.txt', 'r')
        Lines = file1.readlines()
       
        for line in Lines:
            dohlcACv.append(line.strip())

                #

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def averagesDoIt():
    #
    try:
        #
        for x in range(len(dohlcACv)):
            if x < longerVal:
                longerAvg.append(0.00)
            else:
                sum = 0.00
                for y in range(x):
                    temp = dohlcACv[y].split(",")
                    #print(temp[0])
                    #print(temp[1])
                    #print(temp[2])
                    #print(temp[4])
                    if y in range(x-longerVal, x):
                        sum = round(sum + round(float(temp[4]), 2), 2)
                add = round(sum / longerVal, 2)
                longerAvg.append(add)
                #
                #
        #
        for x in range(len(dohlcACv)):
            if x < shorterVal:
                shorterAvg.append(0.00)
            else:
                sum = 0.00
                for y in range(x):
                    temp = dohlcACv[y].split(",")
                    #print(temp[0])
                    #print(temp[1])
                    #print(temp[2])
                    #print(temp[4])
                    if y in range(x-shorterVal, x):
                        sum = round(sum + round(float(temp[4]), 2), 2)
                add = round(sum / shorterVal, 2)
                shorterAvg.append(add)
                #                

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def isThereACrossOver():
    #
    try:
        for z in range(len(dohlcACv)):
            if shorterAvg[z] == 0.00 or longerAvg[z] == 0.00:
                pass
            else:
                if shorterAvg[z] > longerAvg[z]:
                    print("golden crossover matey")

                #

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



def letsSeeHowWeDid(z):
    #
    try:
        global inPosition, profit, alreadyExperiencedDeathCross, numOfLosses, numOfWins, boughtPrice, soldPrice
        #
        if shorterAvg[z] == 0.00 or longerAvg[z] == 0.00:
            pass
        else:
            if inPosition:
                #temp = dohlcACv[z].split(",")
                #currPrice = round(float(temp[1]), 2)
                currPrice = r.stocks.get_latest_price(tickerSymb, "bid_price", True)
                currPrice = round(float(currPrice[0]), 2)
                if currPrice > ((boughtPrice * 0.015) + boughtPrice):
                    inPosition = False
                    numOfWins =  numOfWins + 1
                    soldPrice = currPrice
                    print("sold @ " + str(soldPrice) + " " + str(datetime.now()))
                    #print("z = " + str(z))
                    profit =  profit + (soldPrice - boughtPrice)
                elif currPrice < (boughtPrice - (boughtPrice * 0.010)):
                    inPosition = False
                    numOfLosses = numOfLosses + 1
                    soldPrice = currPrice
                    print("sold @ " + str(soldPrice) + " " + str(datetime.now()))
                    #print("z = " + str(z))
                    profit =  profit + (soldPrice - boughtPrice)
                else:
                    pass
            if shorterAvg[z] > longerAvg[z] and not inPosition and alreadyExperiencedDeathCross:
                #print("golden crossover matey")
                inPosition = True
                alreadyExperiencedDeathCross = False
                #temp = dohlcACv[z].split(",")
                #boughtPrice = round(float(temp[1]), 2)
                boughtPrice = r.stocks.get_latest_price(tickerSymb, "ask_price", True)
                boughtPrice = round(float(boughtPrice[0]), 2)
                print("buy @ " + str(boughtPrice) + " " + str(datetime.now()))
                #print("z = " + str(z))
            if shorterAvg[z] < longerAvg[z]:
                #print("golden crossover matey")
                alreadyExperiencedDeathCross = True
            #
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))



# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while True:


    if not running:
        getLoggedIntoRH()
        running = True
        #

    else:
                    
        time.sleep(1.0)            
        counter = counter + 1


        if counter == 5:
            
            pollingPriceForTickerSymbol("ssss")
            #
            readData()
            #
            averagesDoIt()
            #
            letsSeeHowWeDid(len(dohlcACv) - 1)
            #
            counter = 0
                

            try:
                f2 = open("status.txt", "w")
                f2.write("\n")
                
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.write("PnL =  " + str(profit))
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.write("\n")

                f2.write("number of wins = " + str(numOfWins))
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.write("number of losses = " + str(numOfLosses))
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.write("total number of trades = " + str(numOfLosses + numOfWins))
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.write("\n")

                if (numOfLosses + numOfWins) == 0:
                    f2.write("Wins percentage =   N/A ")
                    f2.write("\n")
                    f2.write("\n")
                else:
                    f2.write("Wins percentage = " + str(numOfWins / (numOfLosses + numOfWins)))
                    f2.write("\n")
                    f2.write("\n")

                if inPosition:
                    f2.write("We are currently in a position")
                else:
                    f2.write("no open positions")
                
                f2.write("\n")
                f2.close()
                    
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
```

Comment: here is a video showing what I am talking about and/or experiencing ....  https://youtu.be/iFYVEtfOyPw

Comment: Others will be able to help you better if you can provide a minimal reproducible example - see here for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . If you can profile your code (see here for guidance: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-profile-your-code-in-python-e70c834fad89), you'll likely be able to identify the function that is causing the bottleneck and refine your question to ask just about the problematic function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with me forgetting to clear my variable list `dohlcACv`, because it was getting ever-increasing in size; so using

```
clear()
```

on my list helped resolve this for me.